# Can systemd DynamicUser= be used with service units using GNU Mailutils?

Tags: systemd

I am using systemd 253.5 and my goal is to tighten my systemd service unit by using `DynamicUser=`. The unit uses GNU Mailutils 3.15 to send emails with the `mail` command.

```
[root@server1.example.com:~]# systemctl cat unit-status-mail@.service
# /etc/systemd/system/unit-status-mail@.service
[Unit]
After=network.target
Description=Unit Status Mail Notifier

[Service]
Environment="LOCALE_ARCHIVE=/nix/store/5l0qzzkb3r3yxygdq3688fjcc18lwg3j-glibc-locales-2.37-8/lib/locale/locale-archive"
Environment="PATH=/nix/store/n0wyrb99dxinh0y6rjixmqdgvbm57fa6-mailutils-3.15/bin:/nix/store/f11ibsj5vmqcy8ihfa8mzvpfs4af7cw5-coreutils-9.1/bin:/nix/store/jvh4fbqfxwwn162k5hb8ndc4h5555wfa-findutils-4.9.0/bin:/nix/store/rn5b13lbsslbvmmbqnqxdcagzqp4435w-gnugrep-3.7/bin:/nix/store/w64nwxs3r6cyqgy6ssxib5i2r6k8yfc2-gnused-4.9/bin:/nix/store/8lgs0dqh9ks1164fp4g14gq7w1ihjbf0-systemd-253.5/bin:/nix/store/n0wyrb99dxinh0y6rjixmqdgvbm57fa6-mailutils-3.15/sbin:/nix/store/f11ibsj5vmqcy8ihfa8mzvpfs4af7cw5-coreutils-9.1/sbin:/nix/store/jvh4fbqfxwwn162k5hb8ndc4h5555wfa-findutils-4.9.0/sbin:/nix/store/rn5b13lbsslbvmmbqnqxdcagzqp4435w-gnugrep-3.7/sbin:/nix/store/w64nwxs3r6cyqgy6ssxib5i2r6k8yfc2-gnused-4.9/sbin:/nix/store/8lgs0dqh9ks1164fp4g14gq7w1ihjbf0-systemd-253.5/sbin"
Environment="TZDIR=/nix/store/4faw3w020cjxvd1dnxhg73mi10wcxvpw-tzdata-2023c/share/zoneinfo"



CapabilityBoundingSet=
ExecStart=/nix/store/1asmwq09fdn42k8rw09ps3jwsq6b0pqf-unit-status-mail/bin/unit-status-mail "me@example.com" "notifications@server1.example.com" %I \
  "     Pretty hostname: Server 1" \
  "  Authoritative FQDN: server1.example.com" \
  "          Machine ID: %m" \
  "             Boot ID: %b"

IPAddressDeny=any
LockPersonality=true
MemoryDenyWriteExecute=true
PrivateDevices=true
PrivateNetwork=true
PrivateTmp=true
ProtectControlGroups=true
ProtectHostname=true
ProtectKernelModules=true
ProtectKernelTunables=true
ProtectSystem=strict
RemoveIPC=true
RestrictAddressFamilies=AF_UNIX
RestrictNamespaces=true
RestrictRealtime=true
RestrictSUIDSGID=true
SystemCallArchitectures=native
SystemCallErrorNumber=EPERM
SystemCallFilter=@system-service
SystemCallFilter=~@privileged
SystemCallFilter=~@resources
Type=simple
UMask=0077

[root@server1.example.com:~]# cat /nix/store/1asmwq09fdn42k8rw09ps3jwsq6b0pqf-unit-status-mail/bin/unit-status-mail
#!/nix/store/7q1b1bsmxi91zci6g8714rcljl620y7f-bash-5.2-p15/bin/bash

MAILTO="$1"
MAILFROM="$2"
UNIT="$3"

EXTRA=""
for e in "${@:4}"; do
  EXTRA+="$e"$'\n'
done

UNITSTATUS="$(systemctl status $UNIT)"

mail \
  --content-type 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' \
  --append=From:"$MAILFROM" \
  --subject="Status for unit: $UNIT" \
  "$MAILTO" <<EOF
Status report for unit: $UNIT

$EXTRA

$UNITSTATUS
EOF
```

`DynamicUser=` implies `ProtectSystem=strict` and that is preventing my unit to send emails with GNU Mailutils 3.15: `mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status`. With `ProtectSystem=full` it works fine.

I suppose I could use `ReadWritePaths=` to make it work again but I do not know what paths are needed.

What paths does the systemd unit need for GNU Mailutils to work?